# Docusign Automatic Recipient List

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I have a problem that no one has been able to help with yet.

I have created a "Send Agreement" Account button in Salesforce that is linked to my default Docusign template ID using their DST command.  This works, but what I need to do is to pull the signers (contacts) who need to sign the document based off of a custom field named, "Signing Role".  The button should pull only those account contacts who have a signing role defined in their respective contact records.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!!

Shaun

Comment: This is doable through the custom button parameters, see my answer below...

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the signers based on their Contact Role by using the custom button parameters **CCRM** and **CCTM**.

Say that you have several Contact Roles in an Opportunity, but you only want to pull out those contacts with role `Business User`. The partial script might look something like this:

```
// CCTM Maps Salesforce Role with a DocuSign TYPE (Signer, Carbon Copy, etc.)
// CCRM Maps Salesforce Role with a DocuSign ROLE (Signer 1, Signer 2, etc.). Usually used with DTS to call template
CCTM=’Business User~Signer’;
CCRM=’Business User~Signer 1’;
```

So the code above implies that the Business User will be Signer 1 and will act to sign the document. If he is using a custom field SigningRole created in Opportunity to determine the role, it might look look something like this:

```
CCTM=’{!Opportunity.SigningRole}~Signer’;
CCRM=’{!Opportunity.SigningRole}~Signer 1’;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I will see if I can enhance on what exactly I am trying to do.

Comment: I am sending a predefined DocuSign (DS) template from a Salesforce (SF) account to multiple contacts related to that account.  The distinction I want to make is that I only want to send the DS to the contacts for the account I am sending from that have a value in the SF "Signing Role" custom field.  In other words, there will more than likely be contacts who aren't owners who won't be signing the document.  The custom field I created is the contains the same values as the DS template signing roles do.

Comment: Ex: SF Signing Role Fields: "Primary Owner, 2nd Owner, 3rd Owner, 4th Owner, 5th Owner" and the DS Signing roles: "Primary Owner, 2nd Owner, 3rd Owner, 4th Owner, 5th Owner".  Hope this helps!